# why does the quantity of information necessary is $N^2$ for an adjacancy matrix to display either 1-regular graphs or simple graphs

Tags: graph-theory

In my book *Graphes et algorithmes*  it is said that he adjacency matrice allows to display either 1-regular graphs (oriented) or simple graphs (unoriented)

We see furthermore that  the quantity of information necessary is $N^2$ ($N=[X]$ the vertex number). Why so?

It is said then that  for low density graphs ($M\ll N^2$ and for the oriented graphs, $M\ll \frac12N(N+1)$) there is a serious lack of information, and it would be advantageous to describe solely the non-zero terms of the adjacency matrice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because that adjacency matrix has one row per vertex and one column per vertex and entries that could be either $0$ or $1$, thus resulting in $N^2$ "bits"?

If we forbid loops, this just says that the diagonal is $0$, taking us down to $N^2-N$ bits. If we consider edges as undirected, the matirix becomes symmetric, leaving us with $\frac{N(N-1)}2$ bits. That is still quadratic in $N$.

Now assume you are not interested in general graphs, but only in a special class, for example rooted trees. A more concise way to encode such a tree is merely list for each non-root vertex its next neighbour closer to the root. That can easily be done with $\sim N\log N$ bits, which is asymptotically much less than $N^2$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Still, I didn't understood your example with roots. In adjacency matrices, we're looking for all adjacent vertex but for a list for each non-root vertex its sole next neighbour closer to the root? How does $log(N)$ appears?

Comment: @Marine1 because it takes about $\log_2N$ bits to encode a number $\le N$